# Android import database from external storage

Tags: android, sqlite, import

I'm trying to import the database file from an external drive (USB), to restore the backup data. The file exists and the path is right, but the database is not imported, this is my code:

```
File usb = new File("/storage/UsbDriveA/BackupHM/database.db");
File currentDB = getDatabasePath("database.db");

FileChannel source = null;
FileChannel destination = null;
String backupDBPath = "/storage/UsbDriveA/BackupHM/database.db";
File backupDB = new File(usb, backupDBPath);
                        try {
                            source = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                            destination = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                            source.close();
                            destination.close();
                            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Restore ok"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast1.show();
                            finish();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ("Error!"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What failure are you seeing? Does the posted code throw an IOException?  I copied your code and successfully transferred a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding error.  Change the block of declarations to this:

```
        //File usb = new File("/storage/UsbDriveA/BackupHM/database.db");
        File currentDB = getDatabasePath("database.db");

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        String backupDBPath = "/storage/UsbDriveA/BackupHM/database.db";
        File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);
```